# How do I radial gradient shade an open object?

Tags: shaders

Not a plane or a sphere.

Like the attached blend file.

Either, for example, white at both ends, black in the middle or black at both ends, white in the middle.

A gradual gradient from one to the other side, linear from left to right, up, down, doesn't matter, or from the outside of the object in, or the inside of the object out. Saving it as an image wouldn't accomplish the same objective.

When I try, Radial doesn't seem to do it.  Neither does quadratic sphere. Nor gradient texture.

Most of what I've seen applies to closed objects like spheres, or flat, or flat surfaces, like planes.

[image: Polylink]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple *[gradient texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/gradient.html#gradient-texture-node)* would do this. Use a gradient texture (I used spherical) with *object texture coordinates* (add the object you want the coordinates to come from in the [*Texture Coordinate node*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html#texture-coordinate-node)), and a [*Color Ramp](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/color_ramp.html#color-ramp-node) ([*Ease* interpolation*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/templates/color_ramp.html#color-ramp-widget) would probably give the best result) to adjust the contrast as a mask between two shaders as shown below:

[image]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

Also, it is important to *apply scale* to see correct results.

---

This should give you a result like this:

[image]

Here is the modified file:
[image]

Comment: "should". Must be doing something wrong. As best I can figure, I've done what you did.  I'm not getting what you got.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/rV56MX62/

Comment: @fewerjunkjunk very close! Although this is a case where maybe ease interpolation might be easier to manage. You do have an extra stop on the color ramp and it doesn't go from black to white. The Principled BSDF can be any color, but that will determine the color A&B of the gradient. Also, *apply scale*!

Comment: And maybe add, the object origin at the centre of the grad.

Comment: So far, all I'm getting are linear gradients.

Comment: "maybe add, the object origin at the centre of the grad"  - Not sure what this means or how to do it.  I know how to set the origin point of geometry, but, not the gradient.  What I have now just moves the color, by mapping, along the x axis.

Comment: @fewerjunkjunk see my edits

Comment: @Timaroberts - Ctrl-A / Scale (ALL else identical) fixed the radial gradient.  Suppose I wanted black or white at both ends - linear, or a multicolor ramp reversed in the middle from end to end (say RG - B - GR) gradual gradient?

This process works for an in/out, out/in, two color radial.

Comment: @fewerjunkjunk to use color, then the setup should  change slightly and not use the texture as a mask but use the ramp for color and the texture to drive the ramp.

Comment: I've noticed using colors other than black or white in the principled shaders helped in understanding what was going on.  Say, Dark Red and Light Red for example, instead of black and white.  I'm going to play with "texture as a mask" and ramp for color and texture.  (Would that require additional nodes or just a rearrangement of the noodles?)